# dijkstra with adjacency list and minimum heap as queue vs adjacency matrix and a normal array as "queue"

Tags: algorithms, heaps, dijkstras-algorithm

Which one should be faster? I have written a script comparing both run time, initially the implementation with adjacency list and minimum heap performs faster, but as the number of nodes/edges increases, it seems the latter perform faster
Is this result expected?

Comment: min heap should be faster. It just does the job with better complexity. If you are talking about actual run time, then for small graphs maybe a normal array could be faster, since its implementation is much simpler. Also, could you elaborate on the type of heap data structure you are using? (binary, binomial, Fibonacci, etc.)

Comment: i am using a binomial graph (erdos_renyi_graph)

Comment: I'm asking about the implementation of the heap, not the graph. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants) for a comparison of some of the different heap types there are